# Using CURL with json against ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, json, curl

there is something I can't well understand.

When I'm using curl against a freshly raw ASP.NET app with JSON using this command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"abc","password":"abc"}' https://localhost:5001/api/values --insecure -v
```

I have a failed response (bad request 400) with the following error:

```
{"":["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1."]}
```

However... If I copy the json data in a file and call the CURL command as this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @user.json https://localhost:5001/api/values --insecure -v
```

It works just fine.

====> Why/How the hell?

Thanks

Comment: What did you send? You don't really know. Obviously, curl did something different in those two cases. Use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to see what was really sent to the service.

Answer (score 1):

this happens to me all the time and I always forget!

Simple fix, the inline data for curl doesn't auto escape the double quotes, so all you have to do is :

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"username\":\"abc\",\"password\":\"abc\"}" https://localhost:5001/api/values --insecure -v
```

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, the `curl` version for Windows doesn't behave the same as the other ones. Either use double quotes or use the Linux `curl` version from the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

**Long explanation**

If different curl calls result in different responses, it's clear that *curl* does something different, not ASP.NET. Using a debugging proxy like Fiddler shows that the first call sends :

```
POST http://localhost:5001/api/values HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5001
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 29

'{username:abc,password:abc}'
```

Replacing single and double quotes with :

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{'username':'abc','password':'abc'}" http://localhost:5001/api/values --insecure -v -x 127.0.0.1:8888
```

Sends :

```
POST http://localhost:5001/api/values HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5001
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 35

{'username':'abc','password':'abc'}
```

**Usin Windows Subsystem for Linux**

All this can be avoided by using the Linux binaries through the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq). That's a full Linux user space environment. In this case both requests send valid JSON :

```
{"username":"abc","password":"abc"}
```

and

```
{'username':'abc','password':'abc'}
```

Comment: I still get the same error :(, but if I wrap everything with double quotes, it works: curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data "'{"username":"abc","password":"abc"}'" http://localhost:5000/api/values --insecure -v

Comment: @MichaelManuelVandycke check the update. You can avoid this if you use WSL and the Linux version of `curl`. I tried it with Ubuntu, there are other distros as well in the Windows App Store, eg SUSE, Kali, Debian

Comment: I use WSL, if I do my curl like this: curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data {"username":"abc","password":"abc"} http://localhost:5000/api/values --insecure -v, I get {"":["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: u. Path '', line 1, position 1."]}.

Comment: However it works with this: curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data "'{"username":"abc","password":"abc"}'" http://localhost:5000/api/values --insecure -v